# Why class.getClassLoader() throws null pointer if cp do not end with a colon?

Tags: java

I have the following Code

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
ClassLoader sysClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)sysClassLoader).getURLs();
    String cp = "";
    for(int i=0; i< urls.length; i++)
    {
        String ffile = (String) urls[i].getFile(); 
    }
}
```

And the class compiles very well - but this is stange. If I start the class this way, I catch a null pointer:

```
java -cp "foo.jar" FileUtils
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: FileUtils
```

But when I start it this way everything is fine:

```
java -cp "foo.jar:" FileUtils
File:/home/u/wzhkit/java/foo.jar
```

Why is this and how can I get around this?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: It is not due to what your code does; it simply does not find the main class to execute it. No null pointer at all.

Comment: No need for quotes around path values. Char : is a path separator under Linux.

Comment: I see a `NoClassDefFoundError`, where do you catch a `NullPointerException`? (or is it a typo in your question?)

Comment: *Where* do you expect class `FileUtils`? inside the jar or is it a separate class file?

Comment: sorry you are right ClassNotFound exception - but when I add the path seperator to the end everything is fine. when not than it raises an exception. usualy do do not have to end the classpath with a path seperator - do you?

Comment: You have not included the (correct) FileUtils.class in your jar file

Comment: @J-16 SDiZ: aahhh I see thank you very much - solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a bit unexpected.

I suspect that what is happening is that `java` is not finding the `FileUtils` class in your JAR file.  Rather I suspect that it is finding it in the current directory, because the `java` command is interpreting an empty classpath entry to mean the current directory.

This is unexpected because according to the [online documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html), you should use "." to refer to the current directory.

---

(Note: this is only a theory ... )

Comment: My theory too... I found no note on *empty classpath entries* on oracles pages...